# server seems like restoring like begining

Tags: restore

I just newbie on linux. 
I have one ubuntu server that has been running almost 1 months. but today seem like my server restoring same as the first day I have installed. tasy to see last login on server with command $last the last command is today. how I can get full login and bash history to see my server activity. thanks

*sorry my english is not good

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  `history` will display your BASH history  (I only use BASH so i'm not sure if it's the same if you use other shells).  By default it doesn't record date/times unless you configured it to, and depending on release [of Ubuntu], if you are logged in locally not all commands will be recorded (I love this feature, but it too can be disabled; commands executed remotely are always recorded).  You didn't specify your release so it may vary on your release, or if you altered your default/configs.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man last` and do something like

```
last --fulltimes --hostlast  --dns --limit 999
```

As an aside, you should consider installing the `man` pages for your language.

Select from the results of

```
apt-cache search manpages
apt-cache search language
```